# I want to calculate all non working time of employee according to shift start time and their all start & end time either in php

Tags: php

Here is data

```
Shift Start Time======== 07:00:00
Shift End Time========== 15:00:00
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (               
            [startTime] => 07:00:00
            [endTime] => 07:50:00
            [elapsed_mins] => 50                
        )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (                       
        [startTime] => 08:50:00
        [endTime] => 09:50:00
        [elapsed_mins] => 20

    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (            
        [startTime] => 09:50:00
        [endTime] => 10:10:00
        [elapsed_mins] => 20           
    ))
```

> here as you can see there the first worked time same as shift start
>   time so that is fine but in second record there is a gap from 7:50:00
>   to 08:50:00 so I want this non working record also into the same array
>   as 2nd object and in last you can see there is no record after
>   10:10:00 to 15:00:00(shift end time)  so i want this record also into
>   the same array. finally there should be five elements into the array.
>   Please help.

according to the above question, desired result should be.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (               
            [startTime] => 07:00:00
            [endTime] => 07:50:00
            [elapsed_mins] => 50                
        )
[1] => stdClass Object
        (               
            [startTime] => 07:50:00
            [endTime] => 08:50:00
            [elapsed_mins] => 60                
        )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (                       
        [startTime] => 08:50:00
        [endTime] => 09:50:00
        [elapsed_mins] => 60

    )
[3] => stdClass Object
    (            
        [startTime] => 09:50:00
        [endTime] => 10:10:00
        [elapsed_mins] => 20           
    )
[4] => stdClass Object
    (            
        [startTime] => 10:10:00
        [endTime] => 15:00:00
        [elapsed_mins] => 290           
    )
)
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? also post your code here

Comment: You provided the data. Please provide the code as well.

Comment: Do you want the total Time or all the details into array as  well

Comment: all the details info as well. I have update the desired result also. Please have a look on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have created a custom code as per your desired output

```
$shift_start_time = '07:00:00';
$shift_end_time   = '15:00:00';

$i             = 0;
$last_end_time = $shift_start_time;
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if ($last_end_time != $value->startTime)
    {
        $sTime   = $last_end_time;
        $eTime   = $value->startTime;
        $elapsed = (strtotime($eTime) - strtotime($sTime)) / 60;
        array_splice($array, $i, 0, (object) array(array('startTime' => $sTime, 'endTime' => $eTime, 'elapsed' => $elapsed)));
    }
    $last_end_time = $value->endTime;
    $i++;
}

$last_worked = end($array);

if ($last_worked->endTime !== $shift_end_time)
{
    $startTime = $last_worked->endTime;
    $endTime   = $shift_end_time;
    $elapsed   = (strtotime($endTime) - strtotime($startTime)) / 60;

    $array[] = (object) array('startTime' => $startTime, 'endTime' => $endTime, 'elapsed' => $elapsed);
}


var_dump($array);
```

This will return below output

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'startTime' => string '07:00:00' (length=8)
      public 'endTime' => string '07:50:00' (length=8)
      public 'elapsed_mins' => string '50' (length=2)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'startTime' => string '07:50:00' (length=8)
      public 'endTime' => string '08:50:00' (length=8)
      public 'elapsed_mins' => string '60' (length=2)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'startTime' => string '08:50:00' (length=8)
      public 'endTime' => string '09:50:00' (length=8)
      public 'elapsed_mins' => string '60' (length=2)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'startTime' => string '09:50:00' (length=8)
      public 'endTime' => string '10:10:00' (length=8)
      public 'elapsed_mins' => string '20' (length=2)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'startTime' => string '10:10:00' (length=8)
      public 'endTime' => string '15:00:00' (length=8)
      public 'elapsed' => int 290
```

**Please note**: Before posting question on SO please try doing it yourself and post your code here. People on SO are here to help you solve problems in your code, not to help you create the whole code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Nishant.
But it will add only last object into array, how it will work for 2nd (index) object there is also a gap from 07:50:00 to 08:50:00.

Comment: you are welcome.. consider voting-up the answer.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just describe the logic, you can make the syntax proper and as per requirement can create multiple loops.

Shift Start Time======== 07:00:00
Shift End Time========== 15:00:00

Now first Calculate the total time required for Shift time

```
$TotalWorkingTime = ($endShiftTime - $ShiftStartTime)* 60 ; // 60 for converting into the min

$totalHourEmp = Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (               
                                [startTime] => 07:00:00
                                [endTime] => 07:50:00
                                [elapsed_mins] => 50                
                            )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (                       
                            [startTime] => 08:50:00
                            [endTime] => 09:50:00
                            [elapsed_mins] => 20

                        )
                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (            
                            [startTime] => 09:50:00
                            [endTime] => 10:10:00
                            [elapsed_mins] => 20           
                        )) ;


// Loop for the employee hours worked

$hourworked = 0 ;
for($cnt = 0 ; $cnt < count($totalHourEmp) ; $cnt ++ )
{
    $hourworked = $hourworked + (($totalHourEmp[$cnt]['endTime'] - $totalHourEmp[$cnt]['startTime']) * 60 )
}

$totalNONworkingHours = $TotalWorkingTime  - $hourworked;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering mate, my desired result is mentioned above please have a look.

Comment: Okay , then you have to take the end time of previous array and find out the remaining time

Comment: yes right I was doing the same but was unable to do that. please help